# Hibernate HQL - LEFT JOIN with subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Is it possible in Hibernate to do a query like this?
I retrieve an error at the subquery position.

```
select *
from table1 as t1 
  left join (
     select t2.* 
     from table2 as t2 
     where t2.column1='xx' 
        and t2.column2='yy'
) t2 on t1.key = t2.fkKey
where t1.column1='condition'
  and t1.column2='condition';
```

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: Just use Criteria instead of HQL

Comment: You don't actually need the sub-query.

Comment: i need to retrieve data from table2 only with specific condition. 
i tried it in oracle without the subquery but with the table2 condition after the 'where' and it doesn't work correctly

Comment: You need to put the condition into the join clause: `from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.fkKey and t2.column1='xx'  and t2.column2='yy' where t1.column1='condition'`